# How to convert array of objects into form data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling with the conversion of an array containing objects into form data. To be more precise, there is an array with the two objects 'isTitlePicture' and 'file' with the following structure:

```
[
0: {isTitlePicture: true, file: File}
1: {isTitlePicture: false, file: File}
]
```

I want to convert the array to form data with the following structure:

```
{
    {
        "isTitlePicture": "true",
        "file": [Object File],
    },
    {
        "isTitlePicture": "false",
        "file": [Object File],
    }
}
```

However, with my current code (see below) I generate a different output.

```
  let files = this.state.files;
  let formDataImage = new FormData(); // create form formData

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formDataImage.append('images', files[i].file);
    formDataImage.append('isTitlePicture', files[i].isTitlePicture);
}

  for (var pair of formDataImage.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

In my current output all objects are in one list and there is no longer a difference which ' isTitlePicture' and 'File' belong together.

```
{
        "isTitlePicture": "true",
        "file": [Object File],
        "isTitlePicture": "false",
        "file": [Object File]
}
```

I am happy for any clairfication.

Comment: How do you have an object with the properties `"isTitlePicture"` and `"file"` twice? I don't think that's possible

Comment: `[
0: {isTitlePicture: true, file: File},
1: {isTitlePicture: false, file: File}
]` is not a valid array, Can you check your input